# Manage dropdown lists in a sidenav

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to do a side navigation that:

1. Just have ONE open sublist (close other)
2. Select only the clicked link in sublist

There are tons of examples out there, but I have not found any good sample in Vanilla Javascript.

**HTML**

```
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <button class="btn">Module 1</button>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Module 2</button>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var i;

for (i = 0; i < dropdown.length; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    var dropdownContent = this.nextElementSibling;
    if (dropdownContent.style.display === "block") {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "none";
    } else {
      dropdownContent.style.display = "block";
    }
  });
}
```

The complete CSS is found on this Fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/q2en6djg/1/

Any clue, hint or help is appreciated.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/suhailsulu/4vhrg6zw/ check this code

Comment: If you restructure the HTML a bit, you can do this with only CSS :hover rules and such, no JS needed.

Comment: @suhailc Excellent! Any tip how to select a list row?

Comment: @Shilly Any link or sample that shows this?

Comment: @sibert Just to be sure, the reason your current fiddle is not correct is because when module 1 is open, clicking on module 2 will not close module 1 and vice versa?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider an `active` CSS class to make it easier:

```js
var dropdown = document.getElementsByClassName("btn");
var l = dropdown.length;
var i;

for (i = 0; i < l; i++) {
  dropdown[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    for (var j = 0; j < l; j++) {
      if (this != dropdown[j])
        dropdown[j].classList.remove('active')
    }
    this.classList.toggle('active');

  });
}

/*To select the sub item*/
var sub = document.querySelectorAll(".list a");

for (var i = 0; i < sub.length; i++) {
  sub[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
    this.classList.toggle('active');

  });
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", sans-serif;
  font-size: 7em;
}

.sidenav {
  margin-top: 0px;
  height: auto;
  width: 200px;
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 1;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-color: #555;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}

.sidenav a,
.btn {
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 17px;
  color: #fff;
  display: block;
  text-align: left;
  border: none;
  background: none;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  outline: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #777;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

.sidenav a:hover,
.sidenav a.active,
.btn:hover,
.btn.active {
  background-color: #777;
}

.list {
  display: none;
  background-color: #999;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.active+.list {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="sidenav">
  <a href="#">Home</a>
  <button class="btn">Module 1</button>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
  <button class="btn">Module 2</button>
  <div class="list">
    <a href="#">Link 1</a>
    <a href="#">Link 2</a>
    <a href="#">Link 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Temni Afif Elegant solution. But how do I make a list row to persist and stay selected?

Comment: @sibert you mean what exactly by *to persist*?

Comment: @Temni Afif If a user select "Link 2" this row should be selected and the list should not close. It should show "where am I?".

Comment: @Temni Afif Does not select any links? Check out "Subwindows" in http://94.237.25.207:8080 for more info.

Comment: @sibert it's because in this example they are links so they are redirecting to another page. You need to adjust the active ones at the page load

Comment: @Temni Afif So it is the other page that should control the navlist? Any links or examples?